# Should [cascade] be used for CSS? Or better retag to [css-cascade]?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

I saw that [some questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css%20cascade?mode=all) use the tags [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) and [cascade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cascade).

However, the description says [cascade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cascade) should only be used for something about relational databases. In fact, among the more than 900 questions in [cascade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cascade), only twenty-something had the [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) tag too. This made me think these questions are wrongly tagged.

Therefore, I decided to create the [css-cascade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-cascade) tag, and retag the [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css)[cascade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cascade) questions.

I didn't ask it in meta at first because there were so few questions. My fault, I should had.

While doing the retagging, I saw that some of these [cascade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cascade) tags in [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) questions were added by [BoltClock ♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock). I guess a moderator knows more than me, so now I'm not sure whether I was doing something wrong?

Comment: There was no Wiki for the tag until 2012, maybe the usage was ambiguous before then?

Comment: Downvoter, do you disagree with the retag? Please explain your opinion in an answer, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was so long ago I don't even remember adding that tag to those questions. Looking at it now I don't think I would be comfortable having that tag around because it is ambiguous. The wiki that was added serves to reinforce the ambiguity.

I think your decision to create a more specific [css-cascade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-cascade) tag was good. If nothing else it corresponds to the css-cascade specification.

I will retag the rest of the CSS questions. As there are 900 other questions with the [cascade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cascade) tag I'm not going to touch the rest.

(In the next episode: should [css-cascade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-cascade) and [css-specificity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-specificity) be merged? Many, many questions conflate the two terms when in reality they mean completely different things, but is keeping them separate useful?)

Comment: What is the advantage of having the redundant [css-cascade] prefix? Are there really questions that will get the [css-cascade] tag but will *not* be tagged [css]?

Comment: @Cody Gray: No, but the word [cascade] alone has multiple meanings and the community doesn't seem to like having overloaded tags, or tags that depend on other tags for context.

Comment: That is a silly position. What word *doesn't* have multiple meanings? I guess that explains why people keep answering my [android] questions with some nonsense about mobile phones.

Comment: @CodyGray The advantage is that some people (e.g me) may know CSS Cascading but without having a clue about the cascading in relational databases. Now these people can e.g. favorite [tag:css-cascade] and track questions in their area of expertise. The reasoning of having tags is that they allow to classify questions, they aren't useful if they aren't specific enough.